# Node.js and Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Getting started with Node.js and Heroku; I am trying to make sense of the following code, in order to build something of my own:

```
app.get('/db', function (request, response) {
  pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function(err, result) {
      done();
      if (err)
       { console.error(err); response.send("Error " + err); }
      else
       { response.render('pages/db', {results: result.rows} ); }
    });
  });
});
```

Where can I find a tutorial or some comments or explanations for that?

Even though I can do some guessing, a good deal of this code is pretty mysterious.

Currently my main concerns are:

1. What happens if I change the SQL query, replacing it by 'SELECT
   count(*) FROM test_table'? How do I then render the result?
2. What does "done();" do? Is it something I can modify or make use
   of?
3. The parameter "request" is never used. Can it be used for
   something at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before handling heroku, you should first look at tutorials about web application in node.js which will answers your last question.

You can see how works [express.js](http://expressjs.com/), a web framework.

Then look at [node-postgre](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) documentation. You will find your answers about the second question [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres#client-pooling) :

```
//this initializes a connection pool
//it will keep idle connections open for a 30 seconds
//and set a limit of maximum 10 idle clients
var pool = new pg.Pool(config);

// to run a query we can acquire a client from the pool,
// run a query on the client, and then return the client to the pool
pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
  }
  client.query('SELECT $1::int AS number', ['1'], function(err, result) {
    //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
    done();

    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0].number);
    //output: 1
  });
});
```

And finanlly, why don't you just log `result` output after changing the SQL query and look what you get ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned a lot from this answer. Just one question:
How do I see the result of console.log(result.rows[0].number); ??
This must be a newbe question.

Comment: @Michel I think the best thing to do is to use an alias. `SELECT count(*) as count FROM test_table` then you can get your count with `result.rows[0].count`

Comment: Yes, this was exactly my understanding after reading your post above, but since I did not get the result I expected when I tried. I then went for using console.log, seeing no out put I figured out I must be making some mistake or looking at the wrong place and decided to write my last comment.

Comment: Though I haven't yet found out how to use console.log(). Thanks to your help and after some experimenting, I got to the point I could display values I wanted, like COUNT(*) or MAX('somefield').

Comment: After (and while) spending some time dealing with issues like the one in this post. I made my own use case to get some practice with Node.js.
Since other people may be having the same kind of trouble, I thought it might be useful to give access to what I did, hoping it will be useful to someone else at some point. If you are interested take a look here(https://primes-garden.herokuapp.com/). There is a link at the bottom for developers (How That Works?).